# Must the subject be "I" when I start a sentence with "Considering"?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I think the best way to do this is using the examples below:

> Considering it's going to be summer in Australia, you don't need to
>   take that many clothes with you.

Is the sentence correct?

Because I think the one that considers it's going to be summer in AU is clearly "me (who says the sentence)", not "you" in the sentence.

So I am wondering if the subject should be "I" in this case, for example:

> Considering it's going to be summer in Australia, I think you don't need to
>   take that many clothes with you.

Comment: Logically, you've come up with a good argument. Really, 'Considering [that] ...' is obviously implying '**I** 've had the thought that since ...'. But it's read as 'I've had the thought that _it's going to be summer in Australia_ ... **consequently** I think ... / you don't .... The 'consequently' may refer either to the 'I've had the thought' _or_ the 'it's going to be summer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering "itself" is ***a preposition*** and ***a conjunction*** as defined:

> preposition& conjunction
>
> Taking into consideration: [as preposition]: ‘considering the
>   circumstances, Simon was remarkably phlegmatic’ [as conjunction]:
>   ‘considering that he was the youngest on the field he played well’

[[Oxford Online Dictionary]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/considering)

Therefore, you don't have to worry about the subject of the independent clause.

Comment: @BananaOnTheWall Glad I could help you.